# (p,n)=1 and if $v \in F$ and $n v \in K$ then prove that $v \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question is part of an assignment I am solving and I am unable to work this out.

> Let char K = p $\neq  0  $ and let n > 1 be an integer such that (p,n)=1 . If $v \in  F$ and
> $ n v \in K$ , then prove that $v \in K$. ( Here K is a subfield of F).

I am not getting idea on which result I should use Can you just give a hint or two for this.

I am learning abstract algebra from I N Hernstein.

Comment: Show that $n$ is invertible in $K$ (or rather $1+\dots+1$ ($n$-times))

Comment: @leoli1 Thanks I have done it